# Scroll a view programmatically

Tags: swift, scroll

I have a text view and I would like to scroll it programmatically (along my video playback). I created an outlet in my *ViewController*:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
```

How can I use it to scroll to a specific character range of my text content?

Answer (score 0):

Try use method `scroll(to:)` from NSClipView ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSClipView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSClipView/scrollToPoint:)) class.

```
let point: NSPoint ...
scrollview.documentView.scroll(point)
```

Comment: My *scrollview* doesn't have *documentView* member.

Comment: Sorry for the bad info: *scrollview* HAS a documentView member, but I want to scroll to a specific character range. Can I do it directly or is there a way to computer the character range to a NSPoint/NSRect value?

Comment: try calculate origin position of specific character directly on your superview and scroll to this processed pos